# Vue.js component html input pattern validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I'm attempting to make html forms that use the input html attribute 'pattern' however when I do so through Vue.js components, its creating very strange behavior. Here is a fiddle to demonstrate.

```
Vue.component('test', {
template:`<input type="text" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}"
title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and be between 8 and 16 characters."/>`
})
```

[jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4gewb23y/2/)

Breakdown of the patterns regex [here (regex101 example)](https://regex101.com/r/7sWJgj/1).

Now for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the normal version validates properly, but the Vue version does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Vue input is missing a backslash on the `\d` pattern. The single `\` gets interpolated away, so you need to double it.

[Escaping in template literals](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html#_escaping-in-template-literals)

> The backslash is used for escaping inside template literals.